# Increase by one the user counter on specific role

Tags: users, user-roles

Hi i work on this code to increase by one the total users at users.php (fake counter)

```
 function my_fake_views($args) {
    
    $users_counts = count_users();
    $total_users = $users_counts['total_users'] +1;

    $args['all'] = "<a href='$url'$class>" . sprintf( _nx( 'All <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'All <span class="count">(%s)</span>', $total_users, 'users' ), number_format_i18n( $total_users ) ) . '</a>';
    return $args;
}
add_filter('views_users', 'my_fake_views');
```

I have 2 questions:

a) how could i do the same for the author role?

b) how could i modify the sprintf and instead of "author" add the text domain for multilanguage use?

Thanks